# Prove or disprove: the inequality $\sqrt{1+x}<1+x/2$ for all $x$ in $(-1,10)$

Tags: real-analysis

So, in this case it's easy to see that it doesn't hold for $x=0$ but how to go about questions asking to prove or disprove more complex or not so obvious inequalities on a certain set?

Comment: It really depends on the functions involved. Perhaps a first approach would be to bring all terms to one side and see if you can simplify the expression in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality should be $\sqrt{x+1}\leq1+\dfrac x2$.

A simple way is to use proof by contradiction. Suppose there is an $x>-1$ such that
$$\sqrt{x+1}>1+\frac x2$$
Observing that $1+\dfrac x2$ is positive for $x>-1$, we can square both sides; this gives
$$x+1>\left(1+\frac x2\right)^2=1+x+\frac{x^2}4$$
which leads to $0>\dfrac{x^2}4$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

This is false.

$x=0$ is a clear counter example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve a simple quadratic inequality-left side is positive, so right too, hence $x \geq -2$ and you can square both of sides.